# Excel - breaking up a cell

Tags: excel

I have part numbers with dashs and numbers for organization purpose, and I was wondering if there's a way I could de-concatenate the string into nearby cells with a formula or two and not go through Data > Text to Columns. Any idea?

Comment: Why not `Text to Columns`? What you have and what you want to achieve?

Comment: This solution should cover what you're looking for: https://superuser.com/questions/483419/how-to-split-a-string-based-on-in-ms-excel

Comment: What does your data look like? What's the expected output? Have you tried `MID()` with perhaps `SEARCH()`?

Answer (score -1):

Here's a demo of a formula-based approach. The formulas will work in Excel.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1LXtKOsxzo1J2-D1e4e_QUqxUug191GHJ5exWSWcoS0s/edit?usp=sharing

It works like this:

`A1` contains the string you want to break up, say `12424-22778-3432626-442-52523262`.

`B2` contains this formula: `=FIND("-",$A1,1)`. This will find us the first occurrence of `-` in A1.

`B3` contains this formula: `=FIND("-",$A1,B1+1)`. This will find us the next  occurrence of `-` in A1 (it starts looking for `-` from the position following what we found in B2.

`B4`... can be copied over from B3. If you copy the cell rather than the formula, the formula will automatically change the reference to `B1` to `C1` and up. In the example, it's copied over all the way to `E1`.

`F1` contains `=mid($A1,1,B1-1)`. This gets us the string from the first char to the `B1-1`th char, i.e.: start to first occurrence of `-`, but without the `-`.

`G1` contains `=mid($A1,B1+1,C1-B1-1)`. You can copy this over up to the second to last cell. The gets us the string from the previous `-` (+1, i.e. without the `-`) to the next `-` (-1, i.e. without the `-`).

`J1` is the last cell and contains `=mid($A1,$E1+1,len($A1))`. It works the same as the previous formula, but goes up to the end of the string in `A1`.